# Run js scripts after partial update of div

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm using dialog in asp.net mvc4 and jQuery 2.1.4. 
I have index page like

```
@model IEnumerable<Osample.Models.Role_Privilege_Map>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "RolePrivilgeMapping";
}

<script>

    $(document).ready(function () {

        registerEditDialogBox();

         $.ajaxSetup({ cache: false });

         function registerEditDialogBox() {
             $(".editRoleDialog").on("click", function (e) {
                 event.stopPropagation();
                 var url = $(this).attr('href');
                 var $this = $(this);
                 $("#dialog-edit").dialog({
                     title: 'Edit Role',
                     autoOpen: false,
                     resizable: false,
                     height: 150,
                     width: 400,
                     modal: true,
                     draggable: true,
                     open: function (event, ui) {
                         $(this).load(url);

                     },
                     close: function (event, ui) {
                        registerEditDialogBox();
                     }
                 });

                 $("#dialog-edit").dialog('open');
                 return false;
             });
         }
    });

</script>


<div id="heading">
    <h2>Role - Privilge Mapping</h2>
</div>

<div id="RolePrivilgeMappingWrapper">

    <div class="float-left" id="roleWrapper">
        @Html.Partial("_Role", sample.Models.DataProvider.DataProvider.GetRoleNames())
    </div>

</div>
```

My role partial page is

```
@model IEnumerable<sample.Models.webpages_Roles>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}

<div class="settingsTable" style="position: relative; width: 100%; margin: 0 auto">

    <div style="width: 50%; margin: 0 auto">
        <div style="width: 50%; margin: 0 auto">
            <h2>Role</h2>
        </div>
    </div>

    <p>
        @Html.ActionLink("Create New Role", "OpenAddRoleDialog", "RolePrivilegeMapping", null, new { @class = "createRole actionHyperLink" })
    </p>
    <table id="tblRole">
        <tr>
            <th>Role ID</th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.RoleName)
            </th>
            <th>Action</th>
        </tr>

        @foreach (var item in Model)
        {
            <tr>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.RoleId)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.RoleName)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "OpenEditRoleDialog", "RolePrivilegeMapping", new { id = item.RoleId }, new { @class = "editRoleDialog actionHyperLink" }) |
                    @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "DeleteRole", "RolePrivilegeMapping", new { id = item.RoleId }, new { @class = "confirmDialog actionHyperLink" }) 
                </td>
            </tr>
        }
    </table>

    <div id="dialog-edit" style="display: none">
    </div>

</div>
```

My edit role partial page is

```
@model sample.Models.webpages_Roles


    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryui")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")


    @Styles.Render("~/Content/css")
    @Styles.Render("~/Content/jqueryUI")

<script type="text/javascript">


    $.validator.unobtrusive.parse(document);

    function roleEditSuccess() {

       // $("#dialog-edit").dialog('close');
    }

</script>
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("EditRole", "RolePrivilegeMapping", 
    new AjaxOptions { HttpMethod = "POST",UpdateTargetId="roleWrapper",OnSuccess="roleEditSuccess" }))
{
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)

    <fieldset>
        <legend>webpages_Roles</legend>

        @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.RoleId)

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.RoleName)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.RoleName)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.RoleName)
        </div>

        <p>
            <input type="submit" value="Save" />
        </p>
    </fieldset>
}
```

So the flow is like

1. Index is loaded with roles
2. Roles table is having edit action link
3. On clicking edit , jquery dialog box is opened and the edit page is shown
4. On saving the details are updated using ,

> UpdateTargetId="roleWrapper"

Because the partial updating of role div, when the dialog box is closed i apply the jquery dialog plugin again, But the following error comes in

> "Error: cannot call methods on dialog prior to initialization;
>   attempted to call method 'open' "

How to proceed here. Am in great problem.

Comment: Why are you rendering your scripts in `partial page`?? Aren't they rendered in `Layout`??

Comment: That is for the ajax validations to work [$.validator.unobtrusive.parse(document)]

Comment: I strongly feel that it is the one causing problem because the error clearly states that you are trying to call a function `open` of dialog before initializing it..

Comment: I have done it as per a post in stack overflow.

Comment: Try changing it and keep all your script rendering part in main layout page!!

Comment: Ok that worked.
removed the bundle from partial page and copied the code  "roleEditSuccess". That  fixed the issue

Comment: @Guruprasad Rao One more help. I tried to close the dialog box in roleEditSuccess() as   $("#dialog-edit").dialog('close');

Am getting same error. how can i Close the modal box after updation

Comment: Same error in the sense!! Error like `attempted to call method 'open' "` or `attempted to call method 'close' "`

Comment: @Guruprasad Rao Yes.After updation I some how has to close the dialog.Am in my learning phase of MVC.

Comment: That should usually work. Cannot tell what's blocking without checking the flow!!

Comment: K Leave it. That worked. Complete mess. Real pain when jquery and MVC comes

Comment: I won't say so! It's real beauty if you understand it properly.. :) I just loved the combination!! .:)